# how request.profile can be used in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

I came by a code that was using req.profile for reading data.How is this possible?

```
const listNewsFeed = async (req, res) => {
  let following = req.profile.following
  following.push(req.profile._id)
  try{
    let posts = await Post.find({postedBy: { $in : req.profile.following } })
                          .populate('comments.postedBy', '_id name')
                          .populate('postedBy', '_id name')
                          .sort('-created')
                          .exec()
    res.json(posts)
  }catch(err){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Repo link:https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-social/blob/second-edition/server/controllers/post.controller.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). In Express, before a request hits a route handler (what you're referencing), it can go through a series of middlewares that can add or modify the request or response objects.

[Here](https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-social/blob/4a81f6c87b98fe54a8c92d33a6302f58876ecde1/server/controllers/user.controller.js#L34) is where it sets `req.profile`:

```
const userByID = async (req, res, next, id) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findById(id).populate('following', '_id name')
    .populate('followers', '_id name')
    .exec()
    if (!user)
      return res.status('400').json({
        error: "User not found"
      })
    req.profile = user
    next()
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status('400').json({
      error: "Could not retrieve user"
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this profile can be used by all the endpoints after this?

Comment: This function calls `next()` which will run the next piece of middleware (defined in [this](https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-social/blob/4a81f6c87b98fe54a8c92d33a6302f58876ecde1/server/routes/post.routes.js#L33) file), and since the `req` object is the same, `req.profile` is accessible. So for endpoint `/api/posts/feed/:userId`, this `userByID` function runs, sets the profile, and then is accessible by `listNewsFeed`.

Comment: It may be helpful to run it locally to experiment with it, adding `console.log` statements in these functions or using a debugger to see this more closely.

Comment: but every request is different right? how can another request can be referneced by another endpoint?

Comment: You're correct that every request is different. But Express works with middleware, so you have a series of functions that run for each request. When a request comes in, it'll start by running `userByID`, and then call `next()`. `next` will call the function `requireSignin`, and when that calls `next()`, it'll call `listNewsFeed`. So each request goes through a series of functions before returning a response.

Comment: I understood abt how `requiresignin` and `listnewsfeed` will run as `/api/posts/feed/:userId` has both as its middlewares but didn't understand why userById middleware will run as its no where mentioned as a middleware in `/api/posts/feed/:userId` route.

Comment: @HimanshuRanjan ah, but at the bottom of that file I linked in my previous comment, there’s router.param(“userId”, userByID) which will run on any endpoint with that query parameter.